# How can I check using javascript or vbscript that a url has loaded completely or not?

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I have a set of url.I need to check whether those url have loaded completely or not and record the time taken to for the page to load completely.I can take care of the time if somehow I know how can I know if that url is loaded completely using java script or vbscript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **javascript** to control `iframe` event **Like**:

```js
var beforeLoad;
function newSite() {
   beforeLoad = (new Date()).getTime();
   $("#res").html('loading...');
   //loadURL(document.getElementById('urltext').value);//to deal with The X-Frame-Options response header
   document.getElementById('myframe').setAttribute('src', document.getElementById('urltext').value) ;
} 
$('#myframe').load(function(){
 $("#res").html('This request took '+(new Date().getTime() - beforeLoad)+' ms');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="https://en.wikipedia.org" id="urltext" />
<input type="button" value="Go" onClick="newSite()" />
<h3 id="res"> </h3>
<br>
<iframe id="myframe" src=""></iframe>
```

And it can deal with The X-Frame-Options response header use:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="" id="urltext" />
<input type="button" value="Change site" onClick="newSite()" />
<h3 id="res"> </h3>
<br>
<iframe id="myframe" src=""></iframe>


<script>
var beforeLoad;
function newSite() {
   beforeLoad = (new Date()).getTime();
   $("#res").html('loading...');
   loadURL(document.getElementById('urltext').value);
} 
$('#myframe').load(function(){
 $("#res").html('This request took '+(new Date().getTime() - beforeLoad)+' ms');

});

</script>
<script>
//deal with The X-Frame-Options response header
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
var url = iframe.src;
var getData = function (data) {
    if (data && data.query && data.query.results && data.query.results.resources && data.query.results.resources.content && data.query.results.resources.status == 200) loadHTML(data.query.results.resources.content);
    else if (data && data.error && data.error.description) loadHTML(data.error.description);
    else loadHTML('Error: Cannot load ' + url);
};
var loadURL = function (src) {
    url = src;
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20data.headers%20where%20url%3D%22' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=getData';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
};
var loadHTML = function (html) {
    iframe.src = 'about:blank';
    iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
    iframe.contentWindow.document.write(html.replace(/<head>/i, '<head><base href="' + url + '"><scr' + 'ipt>document.addEventListener("click", function(e) { if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "A") { e.preventDefault(); parent.loadURL(e.target.href); } });</scr' + 'ipt>'));
    iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
}
//---
</script>
```